# SQL - Count with distinct on ID

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, distinct

Here is an example of my table structure:

```
Key - Country - Store
1 - Germany- YYY
1 - Germany- YYY
2 - France- XXX
2 - France- XXX
2 - France- XXX
3 - United Kingdom- YYY 
3 - United Kingdom- YYY
4 - Germany- YYY
5 - France- YYY
5 - France- YYY
```

I would like to start a query on this table to get the following result:

```
Country- XXX - YYY
Germany - 0 - 2
France - 1 - 1
United Kingdom - 0 - 1
```

The problem for me ist the ID/Key which does not get used once but several times, thats why I cant just use a count query.

What should my query look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `TRANSFORM` function to get this result:

```
TRANSFORM Count(store)
SELECT Country
FROM 
(
  select distinct key, country, store
  from yourtable
) d
GROUP BY Country
PIVOT Store
```

Comment: Hello bluefeet,

that worked perfectly, thank you very much. I didnt know about that pivot function, lovely :)